# 1 Event Handler for 2 Google Charts

Tags: javascript, google-visualization

So, I have two Google bar charts displayed on the same page.I tried creating one event handler for both of them and passing in the chart and data into the selectHandler. Can someone tell me what I'm doing wrong?

```
    google.charts.load('current', {packages: ['corechart', 'bar']});
    google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawBasic);

    function drawBasic() {

     var data1 = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
                ['Condition', 'Frequency'],
                ['Dementia', 6081],
                ['Hypertension', 6055],
                ['Hypercholesterolemia', 6035],
       ]);

     var data2 = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
                    ['Medication', 'Frequency'],
                    ['Naproxen', 7632],
                    ['Plavix', 7486]
    ]);

  var options1 = {
    title: 'Medical Conditions',       
  };

  var options2 = {
    title: 'Medications',
  };

  var conditionbarchart = new google.charts.Bar(
    document.getElementById('conditions_chart'));

  conditionbarchart.draw(data1, options1);


  var medchart = new google.visualization.ColumnChart(
    document.getElementById('medications_chart'));
    medchart.draw(data2, options2);

        google.visualization.events.addListener(conditionbarchart, 'select', selectHandler(conditionbarchart, data1));

        google.visualization.events.addListener(medchart, 'select', selectHandler());
}

           function selectHandler(mychart, mydata){
             var selectedItem = mychart.getSelection()[0];
             if(selectedItem){
                   var selection = mydata.getValue(selectedItem.row, 0);
                   alert('The user selected' + selection);
                 }
           }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's the complete solution to answer my question:

```html
 <html>
  <head>
    <!--Load the AJAX API-->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">

      // Load the Visualization API and the piechart package.
      google.charts.load('current', {'packages':['corechart']});

      // Set a callback to run when the Google Visualization API is loaded.
      google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);

      // Callback that creates and populates a data table,
      // instantiates the pie chart, passes in the data and
      // draws it.
      function drawChart() {

        // Create the data table.
        var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
        data.addColumn('string', 'Condition');
        data.addColumn('number', 'Frequency');
        data.addRows([
          ['Dementia', 3],
          ['Hypertension', 1],
          ['Hypercholesterolemia', 1], 
          ['Coronary artery disease', 1],
          ['Heaches', 2]
        ]);
        
        // Create the data table.
        var data2 = new google.visualization.DataTable();
        data2.addColumn('string', 'Medication');
        data2.addColumn('number', 'Frequency');
        data2.addRows([
          ['Naproxen', 3],
          ['Plavix', 1],
          ['Lasix', 1], 
          ['Insulin', 1],
          ['Neurontin', 2]
        ]);

        // Set chart options
        var options = {

     bars: 'vertical', // Required for Material Bar Charts.
     hAxis: {

        slantedText:true,
        slantedTextAngle:90
     },
     height: 400,
     backgroundColor: {fill: 'transparent'},
     legend: {position: 'none'},
     colors: ['#1b9e77']
   };
                       
        // Set chart options
        var options2 = {

     bars: 'vertical', // Required for Material Bar Charts.
     hAxis: {

        slantedText:true,
        slantedTextAngle:90
     },
     height: 400,
     backgroundColor: {fill: 'transparent'},
     legend: {position: 'none'},
     colors: ['#1b9e77']
   };
 
        // Instantiate and draw our chart, passing in some options.
        var conditionsbarchart = new google.visualization.ColumnChart(document.getElementById('conditions_chart'));
        
        var medchart = new google.visualization.ColumnChart(document.getElementById('medications_chart'));

        function selectHandler(mychart, mydata) {
          var selectedItem = mychart.getSelection()[0];
          if (selectedItem) {
            var topping = mydata.getValue(selectedItem.row, 0);
            alert('The user selected ' + topping);
          }
        }

        google.visualization.events.addListener(conditionsbarchart, 'select', function(){
         selectHandler(conditionsbarchart, data);
        });   
        conditionsbarchart.draw(data, options);
        
        google.visualization.events.addListener(medchart, 'select', function(){
         selectHandler(medchart, data2);
        });   
        medchart.draw(data2, options2);
        
        
      }
      
     

    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <!--Div that will hold the pie chart-->
    <div id="conditions_chart" style="width:400; height:300"></div>
    <div id="medications_chart" style="width: 400; height: 300"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```